# UIView not animated properly using UIView Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am working on UIView Animation. I want to move a view upside while i scroll up and should move down when i scroll down.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGPoint scrollVelocity = [_collectionViewLeaderboard.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:_collectionViewLeaderboard.superview];
if (scrollVelocity.y > 0.0f){
    NSLog(@"going down");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              animations:^ {

                                  _headerview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _headerview.frame.size.width, _headerview.frame.size.height);

                                  _headerviewSecond.frame = CGRectMake(0, _headerview.frame.size.height, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.width, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height);

                                  self.collectionViewLeaderboard.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height+_headerview.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

                                  frameconditon = _headerview.frame;
                                  _viewOptions.frame = CGRectMake(_viewOptions.frame.origin.x,_headerview.frame.size.height+_headerviewSecond.frame.size.height+30, _viewOptions.frame.size.width, _viewOptions.frame.size.height);

                                      } completion:^ (BOOL completed) {

                              }];

}
else if (scrollVelocity.y < 0.0f){
    NSLog(@"going up");

               [UIView animateWithDuration:5.3 animations:^{


                   _headerview.frame = CGRectMake(_headerview.frame.origin.x, -(_headerview.frame.size.height), _headerview.frame.size.width, _headerview.frame.size.height);

                   _headerviewSecond.frame = CGRectMake(0, (_headerview.frame.size.height)-40, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.width, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height);

                   self.collectionViewLeaderboard.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                    frameconditon = _headerviewSecond.frame;

                   _viewOptions.frame = CGRectMake(_viewOptions.frame.origin.x,_headerviewSecond.frame.size.height+20, _viewOptions.frame.size.width, _viewOptions.frame.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: your first if condition will get called too many times. Try changing the view frame without animation and see if your logic works or not.

Comment: First if condition is called while i scroll down, but when come on view controller first time and scroll up else part is executed. At first time uiview jumps down and than move to position which i defined in else block.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its very simple thing if you want to move the view up and down.
Because If you add view in scroll view you can automatically get the view up and down along with the scroll. You just need to set "contentSize" property of scrollView.

If its not the case, you are trying to get panGesture of UICollectionView then you can not get in "scrollViewDidScroll" method.

Here is the useful tutorial on UIPanGestureRecognizer with UICollectionView. Hope so it will help.

https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/using-uigesturerecognizers-with-uicollectionviews